# Power BI reports from Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, devops

I am trying to get reports of all test suites under a suite using power bi. For example a suite - "A" has test suites A1,A2,A3 inside it with all test cases inside A1,A2 and A3. I need to get reports of A1, A2 and A3.Something like groupby("
&"(TestSuite/TitleLevel3),"  or idlevel

Comment: Hi, is there any updates for this issue? Please check whether my answer can help you and feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to get reports of all test suites under a suite using power bi.

You can refer to the method given in the document [Manual test suites aggregated view sample report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-test-plans-aggregate-data-level?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi).

Here is the sample queries:

```
let 
    Source = OData.Feed ("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/TestPoints?" 
        &"$apply=filter((TestSuite/TestPlanTitle eq '{testPlanTitle}' and TestSuite/IdLevel3 ne null))" 
            &"/groupby(" 
                &"(TestSuite/TitleLevel3)," 
                &"aggregate(" 
                    &"$count as TotalCount," 
                    &"cast(LastResultOutcome eq 'Passed', Edm.Int32) with sum as PassedCount," 
                    &"cast(LastResultOutcome eq 'Failed', Edm.Int32) with sum as FailedCount," 
                    &"cast(LastResultOutcome eq 'None', Edm.Int32) with sum as  NotRunCount," 
                    &"cast(LastResultOutcome ne 'None', Edm.Int32) with sum as RunCount" 
            &")" 
        &")" 
        &"/compute(" 
            &"RunCount mul 100 div TotalCount as RunPercentage," 
            &"NotRunCount mul 100 div TotalCount as NotRunPercentage," 
            &"iif(TotalCount gt NotRunCount, PassedCount mul 100 div RunCount,0) as PassedPercentage," 
            &"iif(TotalCount gt NotRunCount, FailedCount mul 100 div RunCount,0) as FailedPercentage" 
        &")" 
        &"&$orderby=RunPercentage desc", null, [Implementation="2.0"]) 
in 
    Source
```

Comment: Aggregated view may not work for me. Because this actually aggregates all the test cases with same test suite name.